# How to display fivestar average infos?

Tags: 7, views, rating

I am building a view with fivestar infos under the voting widget which look like this with the views preview:

[image: views preview]

But it is rendered without the infos in the page:
[image]

In both cases I'm an admin user identified.

 I notice that a whole div with the description class available in the views and including the average/total votes infos is not rendered in the final display.

Is there some configuration to do ? Permission don't seem to be the problem.

**EDIT: So the main issue comes from the theme which is hardcoded from scratch and nothing is displayed unless it is willingly preprocessed or regenerated in a view. I found my way out (see below)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My way out:

For the node rendering:
I used `render($vars['content']['field_fivestar']['#items'][0]['count'])` and `render($vars['content']['field_fivestar']['#items'][0]['average'])` in the template of the node. And then wrap it all in custom html and some if conditions.

For the views list rendering: I recreated the field using one field Fivestar with Rated format + Vote Results : Value based on a relationship 'Content : Vote Results' filtered on Number of votes on the Aggregation Function. Then I completed it with views conditional fields for the different plural / singular / empty alternatives

Answer (score 2):

Have you gone to Display Manager
/admin/structure/types/manage//display
and played with those settings by the gear?

I normally setup display types like "default", "teaser", "teaser- icon side", etc. Then when I create a view, instead of outputting "fields", I output one of these pre-setup display types. I use Display Suite to help get more control of them.

I'm using this votingapi widget in D8 in this way and had no issues.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I found another way, your solution couldn't apply because I ommitted to say (and I just edited my question) that the theme is fully hardcoded from scratch, and every display requires a preprocess function. I gave you a +1 anyway because your answer seems relevant and interesting for a none hardcoded drupal site.